# FFMPEG trimming videos on a docker low cpu setup

Tags: video, cpu, ffmpeg, docker, mp4

So I've been trying to combine multiple mp4s within a docker container running debian Stretch. I have the constraint of not being able to write the output mp4 file to disk, so I need to pipe ffmpeg file output to stdout. I been using the following command.

```
$ffmpeg -i https://clips-media-assets.twitch.tv/214592710.mp4 -i https://clips-media-assets.twitch.tv/214731012.mp4 -i https://clips-media-assets.twitch.tv/28082606352-offset-2786.mp4 -i https://clips-media-assets.twitch.tv/214777342.mp4 -i https://clips-media-assets.twitch.tv/214638267.mp4 -i https://clips-media-assets.twitch.tv/214636156.mp4 -i https://clips-media-assets.twitch.tv/214804499.mp4 -i https://clips-media-assets.twitch.tv/214826823.mp4 -i https://clips-media-assets.twitch.tv/214741267.mp4 -i https://clips-media-assets.twitch.tv/214575427.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v:0] [0:a:0] [1:v:0] [1:a:0] [2:v:0] [2:a:0] [3:v:0] [3:a:0] [4:v:0] [4:a:0] [5:v:0] [5:a:0] [6:v:0] [6:a:0] [7:v:0] [7:a:0] [8:v:0] [8:a:0] [9:v:0] [9:a:0] concat=n=10:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" -map [v] -map [a] -frag_duration 3600 -f mp4 -
```

This results in expected portions of the output video getting trimmed to a few seconds.

Here is ffmpegs output I've read from stdErr where docker's cpu count is 1 with 2 GBs of ram.

```
ffmpeg version 3.4.2-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 6.3.0 (Debian 6.3.0-18) 20170516
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc-6 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gray --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg
libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'https://clips-media-assets.twitch.tv/214592710.mp4':
Metadata:
  major_brand     : isom
  minor_version   : 512
  compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
  encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
Duration: 00:00:21.47, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3678 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc), 1280x720, 3501 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
  Metadata:
    handler_name    : VideoHandler
  Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 163 kb/s (default)
  Metadata:
    handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'https://clips-media-assets.twitch.tv/214731012.mp4':
Metadata:
  major_brand     : isom
  minor_version   : 512
  compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
  encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
Duration: 00:01:00.01, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 8782 kb/s
  Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc), 1280x720, 8606 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
  Metadata:
    handler_name    : VideoHandler
  Stream #1:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 164 kb/s (default)
  Metadata:
    handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #2, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'https://clips-media-assets.twitch.tv/28082606352-offset-2786.mp4':
Metadata:
  major_brand     : isom
  minor_version   : 512
  compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
  encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
Duration: 00:00:30.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6181 kb/s
  Stream #2:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc), 1280x720, 6002 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 90k tbn, 120 tbc (default)
  Metadata:
    handler_name    : VideoHandler
  Stream #2:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 163 kb/s (default)
  Metadata:
    handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #3, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'https://clips-media-assets.twitch.tv/214777342.mp4':
Metadata:
  major_brand     : isom
  minor_version   : 512
  compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
  encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
Duration: 00:00:27.67, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5891 kb/s
  Stream #3:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc), 1280x720, 5715 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
  Metadata:
    handler_name    : VideoHandler
  Stream #3:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 164 kb/s (default)
  Metadata:
    handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #4, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'https://clips-media-assets.twitch.tv/214638267.mp4':
Metadata:
  major_brand     : isom
  minor_version   : 512
  compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
  encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
Duration: 00:00:46.43, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 10449 kb/s
  Stream #4:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc), 1280x720, 10273 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
  Metadata:
    handler_name    : VideoHandler
  Stream #4:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 163 kb/s (default)
  Metadata:
    handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #5, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'https://clips-media-assets.twitch.tv/214636156.mp4':
Metadata:
  major_brand     : isom
  minor_version   : 512
  compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
  encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
Duration: 00:00:07.75, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 8070 kb/s
  Stream #5:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc), 1280x720, 7892 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
  Metadata:
    handler_name    : VideoHandler
  Stream #5:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 163 kb/s (default)
  Metadata:
    handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #6, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'https://clips-media-assets.twitch.tv/214804499.mp4':
Metadata:
  major_brand     : isom
  minor_version   : 512
  compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
  encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
Duration: 00:01:00.01, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6529 kb/s
  Stream #6:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc), 1280x720, 6354 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
  Metadata:
    handler_name    : VideoHandler
  Stream #6:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 163 kb/s (default)
  Metadata:
    handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #7, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'https://clips-media-assets.twitch.tv/214826823.mp4':
Metadata:
  major_brand     : isom
  minor_version   : 512
  compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
  encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
Duration: 00:00:07.68, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3713 kb/s
  Stream #7:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc), 1280x720, 3536 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
  Metadata:
    handler_name    : VideoHandler
  Stream #7:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 163 kb/s (default)
  Metadata:
    handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #8, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'https://clips-media-assets.twitch.tv/214741267.mp4':
Metadata:
  major_brand     : isom
  minor_version   : 512
  compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
  encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
Duration: 00:00:07.19, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5785 kb/s
  Stream #8:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc), 1280x720, 5610 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
  Metadata:
    handler_name    : VideoHandler
  Stream #8:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 165 kb/s (default)
  Metadata:
    handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #9, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'https://clips-media-assets.twitch.tv/214575427.mp4':
Metadata:
  major_brand     : isom
  minor_version   : 512
  compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
  encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
Duration: 00:00:51.01, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3874 kb/s
  Stream #9:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc), 1280x720, 3698 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
  Metadata:
    handler_name    : VideoHandler
  Stream #9:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 164 kb/s (default)
  Metadata:
    handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 (h264) -> concat:in0:v0
Stream #0:1 (aac) -> concat:in0:a0
Stream #1:0 (h264) -> concat:in1:v0
Stream #1:1 (aac) -> concat:in1:a0
Stream #2:0 (h264) -> concat:in2:v0
Stream #2:1 (aac) -> concat:in2:a0
Stream #3:0 (h264) -> concat:in3:v0
Stream #3:1 (aac) -> concat:in3:a0
Stream #4:0 (h264) -> concat:in4:v0
Stream #4:1 (aac) -> concat:in4:a0
Stream #5:0 (h264) -> concat:in5:v0
Stream #5:1 (aac) -> concat:in5:a0
Stream #6:0 (h264) -> concat:in6:v0
Stream #6:1 (aac) -> concat:in6:a0
Stream #7:0 (h264) -> concat:in7:v0
Stream #7:1 (aac) -> concat:in7:a0
Stream #8:0 (h264) -> concat:in8:v0
Stream #8:1 (aac) -> concat:in8:a0
Stream #9:0 (h264) -> concat:in9:v0
Stream #9:1 (aac) -> concat:in9:a0
concat:out:v0 -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
concat:out:a0 -> Stream #0:1 (aac)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x88d3640] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x88d3640] profile High, level 3.2
[libx264 @ 0x88d3640] 264 - core 155 r2901 7d0ff22 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=1 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'pipe:':
Metadata:
  major_brand     : isom
  minor_version   : 512
  compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
  encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, progressive), 1280x720, q=-1--1, 60 fps, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 libx264
  Side data:
    cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
  Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 aac
frame= 2320 fps= 20 q=31.0 size=   25147kB time=00:00:38.50 bitrate=5318.2kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed=0.334x
frame= 4560 fps= 17 q=31.0 size=   62654kB time=00:01:15.83 bitrate=6768.0kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed=0.275x
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x6109940] stream 1, offset 0x1187c5: partial filets/s dup=2 drop=0 speed=0.315x    speed=0.275x
[h264 @ 0x69b8980] Invalid NAL unit size (10904 > 8072).39kB time=00:01:52.43 bitrate=5795.4kbits/s dup=2 drop=0 speed=0.315x
[h264 @ 0x69b8980] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
Error while decoding stream #3:0: Invalid data found when processing input
https://clips-media-assets.twitch.tv/214777342.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input
  Last message repeated 2 times
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x69c01c0] stream 1, offset 0x124bed: partial filets/s dup=4 drop=0 speed=0.314x    0 speed=0.315x
[h264 @ 0x69e5220] Invalid NAL unit size (40844 > 37063).8kB time=00:01:53.36 bitrate=5817.7kbits/s dup=4 drop=0 speed=0.314x
[h264 @ 0x69e5220] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
Error while decoding stream #4:0: Invalid data found when processing input
https://clips-media-assets.twitch.tv/214638267.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input
  Last message repeated 2 times
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x6e34300] stream 1, offset 0x134e04: partial filets/s dup=4 drop=0 speed=0.314x    0 speed=0.314x
[h264 @ 0x6e936e0] Invalid NAL unit size (3219 > 2887).
[h264 @ 0x6e936e0] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
Error while decoding stream #5:0: Invalid data found when processing input
https://clips-media-assets.twitch.tv/214636156.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input
  Last message repeated 2 times
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x6e65f80] stream 1, offset 0x1411c1: partial filets/s dup=5 drop=0 speed=0.314x    0 speed=0.314x
[h264 @ 0x72c63c0] Invalid NAL unit size (5000 > 3708).841kB time=00:01:55.87 bitrate=5856.6kbits/s dup=5 drop=0 speed=0.314x
[h264 @ 0x72c63c0] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
Error while decoding stream #6:0: Invalid data found when processing input
https://clips-media-assets.twitch.tv/214804499.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input
  Last message repeated 2 times
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x779e0e0] stream 1, offset 0x134b57: partial filets/s dup=6 drop=0 speed=0.316x    0 speed=0.314x
[h264 @ 0x7bec920] Invalid NAL unit size (18581 > 8590).18kB time=00:02:05.68 bitrate=5698.0kbits/s dup=6 drop=0 speed=0.316x
[h264 @ 0x7bec920] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
Error while decoding stream #8:0: Invalid data found when processing input
https://clips-media-assets.twitch.tv/214741267.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input
  Last message repeated 2 times
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7bed200] stream 1, offset 0xdb7f6: partial fileits/s dup=6 drop=0 speed=0.317x    0 speed=0.317x
[h264 @ 0x84cbc60] Invalid NAL unit size (1625 > 440).
[h264 @ 0x84cbc60] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
Error while decoding stream #9:0: Invalid data found when processing input
https://clips-media-assets.twitch.tv/214575427.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input
  Last message repeated 2 times
frame= 7655 fps= 19 q=31.0 Lsize=   88771kB time=00:02:07.54 bitrate=5701.5kbits/s dup=8 drop=0 speed=0.316x     speed=0.317x
video:85056kB audio:2074kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.883764%
[libx264 @ 0x88d3640] frame I:40    Avg QP:22.85  size:143772
[libx264 @ 0x88d3640] frame P:2853  Avg QP:26.55  size: 20092
[libx264 @ 0x88d3640] frame B:4762  Avg QP:31.26  size:  5045
[libx264 @ 0x88d3640] consecutive B-frames:  2.8% 41.0%  5.4% 50.8%
[libx264 @ 0x88d3640] mb I  I16..4: 13.8% 21.0% 65.2%
[libx264 @ 0x88d3640] mb P  I16..4:  3.7%  3.7%  3.9%  P16..4: 29.6% 13.4%  6.3%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:39.4%
[libx264 @ 0x88d3640] mb B  I16..4:  0.9%  0.6%  0.6%  B16..8: 21.9%  5.6%  0.8%  direct: 1.6%  skip:68.1%  L0:41.3% L1:46.4% BI:12.3%
[libx264 @ 0x88d3640] 8x8 transform intra:30.7% inter:37.6%
[libx264 @ 0x88d3640] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 57.7% 42.7% 8.6% inter: 10.5% 5.6% 0.4%
[libx264 @ 0x88d3640] i16 v,h,dc,p: 28% 30% 22% 20%
[libx264 @ 0x88d3640] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 28% 24% 22%  3%  3%  4%  5%  4%  5%
[libx264 @ 0x88d3640] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 28% 20% 20%  5%  5%  6%  6%  5%  5%
[libx264 @ 0x88d3640] i8c dc,h,v,p: 66% 18% 14%  2%
[libx264 @ 0x88d3640] Weighted P-Frames: Y:2.4% UV:0.7%
[libx264 @ 0x88d3640] ref P L0: 68.0% 13.8% 15.7%  2.5%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x88d3640] ref B L0: 87.4% 11.4%  1.2%
[libx264 @ 0x88d3640] ref B L1: 98.8%  1.2%
[libx264 @ 0x88d3640] kb/s:5461.32
[aac @ 0x8076a00] Qavg: 721.442
```

The funny thing is when I increase docker's cpu count it seems to trim less and less of the expected output until I give docker 6 cpus. At that point none of the videos get trimmed and combines all of the videos as expected. As well as the "Invalid NAL unit size" errors no longer appearing in the output. As being fairly new to ffmpeg any help on making mp4 concatenation more stable on a low cpu configuration would be great.